# particular field as result in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am newbie to mongodb. I need to know how to retrieve a paricular field alone from document in a collection.

eg:

```
db.things.findOne({name:"mongo"});
```

result:

```
{"_id" : "497dab624ee47b3a675d2d9c" , "name" : "mongo" , "type" : "database"}
```

but in result I need only type field. How to specify it in the find query?

Comment: Know your documentation http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
db.things.findOne({name:"mongo"}, {type : 1});
```

Comment: Just that only this field should be included (and _id). I would suggest to check documentation, posted in another answer (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) It is pretty clear to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
db.things.findOne({name:"mongo"}, {type:1});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.things.find({name:"mongo"}, {type:true, "_id":false}).
```

`_id` will come by default if you don't mark it as false.